# HTML in title attribute is converting to smart quotes in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, smart-quotes

I'm using Bootstrap with Wordpress and attempting to use the title attribute as a source for HTML in a tooltip. This works fine outside of Wordpress, but Wordpress is converting the quotes in the rendered page which breaks the HTML. I'm having difficulty solving this issue.

I tried the remove_filter method before the closing PHP tag in the footer.php file but it didn't work.

```
<area alt="kentucky" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="<h1>KENTUCKY</h1>" coords="0" shape="circle">
```

Comment: Could you show us where it ends up? Some visualization?

Comment: `<` and `>` don't have to be escaped in attribute values. `>` doesn't have to be escaped anywhere in HTML. HTML only requires that you use `&lt;` when `<` would be mistaken for the start of a tag.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what it's doing: http://s14.postimg.org/d9sbtg5wh/Screenshot_2015_09_14_11_35_34.png

Here is a resource that led me to believe I am doing this correctly. 
http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/200/

Plus, I made a fiddle myself and it works fine outside of Wordpress.
http://jsfiddle.net/madphill/g9csy1so/

Comment: @JuanMendes , You're right, I've been working too much in other languages lately xD (Not JavaScript tho)

Comment: @Quention You are correct http://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#attributes-0 mentions that attributes values using double quotes only need to escape double quotes and [ambigous ampersands](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#syntax-ambiguous-ampersand)

Comment: I'm fairly certain the only way to stop this is to prevent WP from processing the quotation marks and it would seem like the remove_filter('the_content'); should do the trick but I'm not having any luck with that so far.

Comment: I've 'solved' it as long as you're willing to have dumbquotes on your site. Using the [wpuntexturize plugin] (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpuntexturize/) Seems to have done the trick. It's not ideal, but it will allow me to move on for now. The typographer in me feels dirty though.